# Is it possible to store query results to reuse in another query in MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a query to search for data that falls within a certain time period like so:

```sql
SELECT id1 
FROM table1 
WHERE (time > '[time goes here]' 
       AND time < '[time goes here]')
```

I am storing and using this data in Python, and then I wish to search for data within the previous result from another table like so:

```sql
SELECT id2 
FROM table2 
WHERE (table2.id1 = '[results from previous query]'.id1 
       AND '[other conditions go here]')

SELECT id3 
FROM table3 
WHERE (table3.id2 = '[results from previous query]'.id2 
       AND '[other conditions go here]')
```

I would have to do this recursively (an undetermined number of times) so it cannot be done manually. Is it possible to use the results from the previous query in any way or would I have to put the entire first query into the second query, and then put the entire second query into the third query? If it is the latter, is there any way to speed this up, as the first query alone takes several seconds and I can't afford to rerun the query multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

you can use CTE like this

```
with data1 as
(
select id2 FROM table2 WHERE
),
data2 as
(
select id3 from table 3 where
)
select * from data1,data2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with data1 as
(
select id2 FROM table2 WHERE
),
data2 as
(
select id3 from table3,data1 where <condition>
)
select * from data2
```

Comment: mysql does not support `with`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution1:**
You could use join:

select t2.id2 from table1 t1,table2 t2 where t2.id2=t1.id1 and t1.time>x and t1.time

**Solution2:**
You could also save the result in a list and then pass it to the next query:
select id2 from table2 where id2 in (list)